# Two classes using each others' member types

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14

I defined a class A and a class B like following:

```
class A
{
public:
    using Type = int;
    B::Type v;
};

class B
{
public:
    using Type = double;
    A::Type v;
};
```

And then I get a compile error

```
 error: 'B' does not name a type
```

The following codes don't work, either.

```
class B;

class A
{
public:
    friend class B; // makes no sense
    using Type = int;
    B::Type v;
};

class B
{
public:
    using Type = double;
    A::Type v;
};
```

You know, a class cannot be defined twice, so A must be defined after B, or B must be defined after A.

How can I use each other's member types?

Methods can be defined outside, but can member types be defined outside a class?

My only solution is to move the types out of the classes.

Comment: You have a [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes) problem here. Do any of these solve your problem? I see you have tried one of them, I think.

Comment: You'll have to make at least one of those typedefs a non-member (or a member of yet third class that doesn't depend on `A` or `B`).

Comment: So the only way is not to use B::Type and redefine a new type not depending B, right?